# Can't seem to have Hibernate 4.1.0 dependencies added

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to add this Hibernate dependency, however, the JAR does not get downloaded somehow.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

After checking the m2 folder, there is no downloaded hibernate core jar. I remember that the new jboss nexus repository site does not need to be added into the pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

At least on the maven repository, the Hibernate Core dependency only exists as version 4.0.1 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.1.Final

I normally add the hibernate entity manager dependency. I did this also for the 4.1 version, and it downloaded the 4.1.0 core.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

For me it was not necessary to add any additional repository.